# Scopes vs class methods in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Are scopes just syntax sugar, or is there any real advantage in using them vs using class methods?

A simple example would be the following. They're interchangeable, as far as I can tell.

```
scope :without_parent, where( :parent_id => nil )

# OR

def self.without_parent
  self.where( :parent_id => nil )
end
```

What is each of the techniques more appropriate for?

**EDIT**

[named_scope.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb) mentions the following (as pointed out below by [goncalossilva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446831/goncalossilva)):

Line [54](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb#L54):

> Note that this is simply 'syntactic
>   sugar' for defining an actual class
>   method

Line [113](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb#L113):

> Named scopes can also have extensions,
>   just as with has_many declarations:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :red, where(:color => 'red') do
    def dom_id
      'red_shirts'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem with scopes is that they can sometimes crowd the top of the model. I'm fairly certain they are just syntax sugar. With rails 3 lazy loading, theres no reason you cant use a class method as you pointed out. At this point, it really comes down to a matter of preference.

Comment: Platsformatec has a very good comparison at http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For simple use cases, one can see it as just being syntax sugar. There are, however, some differences which go beyond that.

One, for instance, is the ability to define extensions in scopes:

```
class Flower < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :red, :conditions => {:color => "red"} do
    def turn_blue
      each { |f| f.update_attribute(:color, "blue") }
    end
  end
end
```

In this case,`turn_blue`is only available to red flowers (because it's not defined in the Flower class but in the scope itself).

Comment: Uuh, that's nifty :) *starts console*