# Am I supposed to do this in helper? or does this make slower?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In this case which pattern will be faster?
Obviously Pattern1 with helper looks much more sophisticated and looks clean.
But it send SQL every time when  user_link method is called.
Here it calls up to 100times at one page loading.

Which way would be better for benchmark performance?

**Pattern1. With helper**

application_helper

```
def user_link(username)
    link_to User.find_by_username(username).user_profile.nickname, show_user_path(username)
end
```

view

```
<% @topics.order("updated_at DESC").limit(100).each do |topic| %>
    <%= user_link(topic.comment_threads.order("id").last.user.username) if topic.comment_threads.present? %>
<% end %>
```

**Pattern2. Without helper. Just only view**

```
<% @topics.order("updated_at DESC").limit(100).each do |topic| %>
    <%= link_to(topic.comment_threads.order("id").last.user.nickname, show_user_path(topic.comment_threads.order("id").last.user.username) ) if topic.comment_threads.present? %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: SQL in your views? Destroy that habit for your own sake. All this finder code should be in your models, not the application controller, and especially not the views.

Comment: @Daimen Thanks for an advise! But how could you code that if I'm doing that with Model??

Comment: What you'd do is have a method in your topic model aptly named `recent` so you could perform something like: `@topics.recent`. You could also create a named scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
# Topics model
#via scope
scope :get_topic_list, lambda do
  order("updated_at DESC").joins(:comment_threads => :user).limit(100)
end

#via method
def self.get_topic_list
  Topic.order("updated_at DESC").joins(:comment_threads => :user).limit(100)
end

# in your controller or move to model itself (recommened)
@topics = Topic.get_topic_list

# in you view
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <%= link_to(topic.comment_threads.order("id").last.user.nickname, show_user_path(topic.comment_threads.order("id").last.user.username) ) if topic.comment_threads.present? %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is this for? Does it make faster?

Comment: it tries to get all the data from the database in less queries.. with your original code you would have an enourmus amount of queries to the database.. see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Thanks. So when I want to constrain records by nested columns, should I use include or joins?? Is that what you mean? If so, include or joins, which one is better??

Comment: @cat: you should better use joins.

Comment: @cat: you should put the joins/order into your controller

Comment: Removed my comment and put it on main question, as I see it wasn't you who wrote the code wholly. You were just illustrating.

Comment: @Thanks for new answer. But what the difference between coding them in view and coding them in controller?

Comment: @Damien Can I make another question, and there could you please show me how to handle this with Model?

Comment: its the seperation of model/buisness logic from the presentation... you could create an method in your model which is fetching the data with all the specified conditions, and then use it in your controller..

Comment: @Lichtamberg Are you talking about making scope?

Comment: @cat sure, create a question on how to structure this better and I'll give you a more detailed response.

Comment: @Damien Thanks. I created another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429702/how-can-i-fetch-records-just-like-below-with-using-model-and-controler-not-view

Comment: @cat I'll answer it now. Though model is one step forward, I'd even venture into a decorator here. No sql or sql builder should ever be used in the view.

Comment: i also posted a version with scope

Comment: Don't forget new conventions ;) `comment_threads: true`. Old hashing syntax has been phased out.

Comment: @Damien Thanks.  Lichtamberg. Thanks for your answer again. Scope or Method in model. Which one is better to use? and why I shouldnt do that in views? Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: There is not really a big difference.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375896/scopes-vs-class-methods-in-rails-3

Comment: i would use a class method, since its not used other wise.. if you would use it very often, then you should use a scope..

Comment: @Lichtamberg With my understanding, scope is for basic usage. If I use scope, it always constrain with the criteria as default. am I right?

Comment: there is no difference between these structures... its just different syntax... scopes are very often chained together (like Users.active.confirmed.count), so its more for frequent use, than special situations (for only one action eg)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23065/discussion-between-lichtamberg-and-cat)