# How can I fetch records just like below with using Model and controler not view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I fetch records just like below with using Model and controler not view?

**Pattern1. With helper**

application_helper

```
def user_link(username)
    link_to User.find_by_username(username).user_profile.nickname, show_user_path(username)
end
```

view

```
<% @topics.order("updated_at DESC").limit(100).each do |topic| %>
    <%= user_link(topic.comment_threads.order("id").last.user.username) if topic.comment_threads.present? %>
<% end %>
```

**Pattern2. Without helper. Just only view**

```
<% @topics.order("updated_at DESC").limit(100).each do |topic| %>
    <%= link_to(topic.comment_threads.order("id").last.user.nickname, show_user_path(topic.comment_threads.order("id").last.user.username) ) if topic.comment_threads.present? %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

```
  <%  @community.topics.eager.recent.each do |topic| %>
    <%= user_link(topic.comment_threads.order("id").last.user.username) if topic.comment_threads.present? %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Am I supposed to do this in helper? or does this make slower?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429408/am-i-supposed-to-do-this-in-helper-or-does-this-make-slower)

Comment: @Lichtamberg not a duplicate, and I've just spent 10 minutes on that answer so I'd appreciate you didn't vote for close (if you were planning to). The other question is about performance, this about structure. I think it deserves its own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL code or SQL builders should never ever reach the view layer. This should be in your models. I wouldn't even place queries like this in the controller.

I'd extract the `topic` SQL builder into a named scope. On top of that, to avoid n+1 queries, I'd create another named scope `eager`:

```
# topic.rb

scope :eager, includes(comment_threads: :user)
scope :recent, lambda { |n = 100| order("updated_at DESC").limit(n) }
```

Then I'd move the `comment_threads` SQL builder into your comment_threads model:

```
# comment_thread.rb

def self.last_user_nickname
  order("id").last.user.nickname
end
```

We can now tidy up your views:

```
<% @topics.eager.recent.each do |topic| %>
  <%= user_link(topic.comment_threads.last_user_nickname) if topic.comment_threads.present? %>
<% end %>
```

Allow me to sell [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) to you (erb alternative):

```
- @topics.eager.recent.each do |topic|
  = user_link(topic.comment_threads.last_user_nickname) if topic.comment_threads.present?
```

I might have even gone a step further and extracted the `user_link` into a `UserDecorator`. See https://github.com/drapergem/draper for details.

## Summary

1. Extract SQL builder for `topic` into `eager` and `recent` scopes under `topic`
2. Extract SQL builder for `comment_threads` into `last_user_nickname` under `comment_thread`
3. Look into extracting `user_link` into a `UserDecorator`
4. Use Slim! :)

Comment: Thanks so much. I cannot tell your answer or previous answer will be faster. What would you think?

Comment: I've completely ignored the performance in this answer, as the other answer puts more focus on it. All you have to do, essentially, is `include` the related objects. You could add an `eager` scope which does this for you, then call `@topics.recent.eager`, or you can hardcode it into the method as the other answer demonstrated.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try some possible way. I just want to know why I shouldn't do these in view. Can you tell me why?

Comment: In fact, I'll polish it up a little with the include. Which I wouldn't hardcode into the method, but instead create a separate scope so it can be reused elsewhere.

Comment: That'll be helpful Thanks so much.

Comment: You were saying "Don't forget new conventions ;) comment_threads: true. Old hashing syntax has been phased out. "  What's this?? am I supposed to do something else if I'm doing with the one in previous?

Comment: @cat don't worry too much about that. The old syntax was `:comment_threads => true`, but is being replaced by `comment_threads: true`. It isn't critical, but you should follow this convention from now on in your Rails projects.

Comment: Thanks! and Thanks for new answer:) I'll try that!

Comment: I get this error. undefined method `recent' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000012136570>

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer. I'd suggest using `named_scopes` for both `eager` and `recent`.

Comment: Now I get this error:( undefined method `named_scope' for #<Class:0x000000127c5170>

Comment: That is an old method! I'll update. `named_scope` was deprecated. It is now just `scope`.

Comment: Thanks now it worked. So now could you tell me why I have to use this way. why not the way with view like my example??

Comment: `recent` scope constrain into latest 10 records. What about `eager`? What is it for???

Comment: @cat There are many benefits, and some important principles. Views should not be responsible for structuring queries. That is a big no no for many reasons. The main benefit is that the code is now far more reusable (you can call `@topics.eager` or `@topics.recent` anywhere) and, as such, far more testable.

Comment: Thanks:) I tried to use `last_user_nickname` but it says undefined method `last_user_nickname' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000000feb0460> do you know why??

Comment: Might be a better idea to even move that to a `named_scope`. The reason is because it should be `self.last_user_nickname`. I do apologize. I wrote most of this straight into the answer box.

Comment: Everything works perfect now. Thanks for everything. This was so useful information. Thanks again!